# All Data Store in one Array using php

Tags: php

while loop generates 12 digit number. Store this numbers outside the while loop in array.

```
for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){
    $active_id=''; 
    $count=0;
    $active_code=''; 
    $myarray = array();
    while ( $count < 12 ) {
        $random_digit = mt_rand(0, 9);
        $active_id .= $random_digit;
        $count++;
    }
    echo $active_id;
}
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: i have print 12 digit number outside the for loop <b>active_id</b>

Comment: <?php

for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){

$active_id=''; 

$count=0;

$active_code=''; 

$myarray = array();

while ( $count < 12 ) {

$random_digit = mt_rand(0, 9);

$active_id .= $random_digit;

$count++;

}
 echo $active_id."<br/>";
}

?>
i have  active_id varible print outside the for loop....

Comment: declare $active_id as a array like this $active_id = array();

Comment: can u give the code. i did not get write solution @RafaelShkembi

Comment: do you know how your code works? Tell me what is the procedure of your code

Comment: actually i have create 12 digit number using whiile loop and this 12 digit code is four time created using for loop. so i have this four digit code (active_id) print outside the for loop.

Comment: Alright, your question in it's current state is unclear. Provide more details and elaborate on the problem. What does your code do? What **should** it do? Show us an expected output.

Comment: @FirstOne can u slove help this code

Comment: I could **try**, if only I knew what you want. Is this somehow what you are trying to do?: [https://eval.in/605832](https://eval.in/605832). It's outside of the loop and you have each number of 12 digits separated

Comment: than you so much bro @FirstOne

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){
    $active_id='';
    $count=0;
    $active_code='';

    while ( $count < 12 ) {
        $value .= mt_rand(0, 9);
        $count++;
        $active_id[$i] = $value;
    }
    unset($value);
    $myarray[] = $active_id;
}
var_dump($myarray);
```

it generates an array with for numbers each having 12 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You get a huge number because you just print the values one after the other. Do it like this, instead:

```
$nums = array();
for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++){
    $active_id=''; 
    $count=0;
    while ( $count < 12 ) {
        $active_id .= mt_rand(0, 9);
        $count++;
    }
    $nums[] = $active_id;
}
echo implode('<br>', $nums);
```

Outputs something like:

```
547806804306
795608578570
440070793444
942559796496
```

---

You can also use a loop to display the values, like so:

```
foreach($nums as $v){
    echo $v . '<br>';
}
```

The output:

```
462186324671
222725884540
242904883364
589742052131
```

---

*Note that I removed a couple variables that weren't really needed.*